# using micro-service architecture through fire base cloud functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

What is the scope of implementing a micro-service architecture using firebase cloud functions? Is it a correct way to do it or is it a step backward. As we have seen fire base is built to be server less application back-end, But with multiple triggers and support for HTTPS should we try to get back to micro services. Just to try I have implemented multiple services on firebase cloud functions which had multiple URLs, they had a really good response time averaging at 500ms

Answer (score 5):

This is a very challenging question to answer.  It is not a step backward, you can think of Cloud Functions as a tool that you can use along with other technologies to implement your microservice strategy.  For instance, if you are going to be leveraging the Firebase Database, and other features within Firebase then it makes sense to use the Cloud Functions for Firebase.

Let's say you don't want to use Cloud Functions for Firebase and you choose another technology such as Kubernetes or App Engine.  First, you'll have to add the firebase SDKs to that stack and make sure it can access your Firebase project.  You get access for free in Cloud Functions for Firebase.  Next, you will write the same code that you would implement in the Cloud Function.  Finally, you will have additional steps for deploying those technologies.  Leveraging Cloud Functions for Firebase will be quicker and more productive.

As time goes on it will become more apparent when to use an additional technology.  I recently wrote a blog post about when I would choose Container Engine over Cloud Functions.  This topic can become subjective since it's really based on your needs, features, and the technologies you are working with.

[Cloud Functions vs Container Engine](https://medium.com/statuscode/cloud-functions-vs-container-engine-5c773e364ced)